# Where do I have to put the code to display the main menu of my game?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-umg

I've just started to learn Unreal Engine and I developing a Pong game using C++.

To create the menu I have used UMG and to learn how to do it, I have watched [Wiring up the Main Menu](https://learn.unrealengine.com/course/3061301/module/6405068?moduletoken=UHxxnDLPW8RbSxt-) tutorial from Unreal Engine Online learning.

To show the Widget with the menu the instructor has created a new empty level and he has used Level Blueprint to
show it. But the instructor said: *"Traditionally, you don't use the level Blueprint for much"*.

So, if we don't have to use the level Blueprint, what do I have to do to display the main menu?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Gamemode for your menu and a Hud class. Load your widget in the hud class on Event BeginPlay.